# How do I convert this SQL query into Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to convert the following SQL query into Sequelize. One of the main confusions I have is how to do this conversion with the consideration the 'types' field is an array. Do I need to use sequelize literals?

```
SELECT * FROM "Cities" WHERE "id" IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT "id" FROM (
            SELECT "id", unnest(types) as "typeId" FROM "Cities"
        ) cityTypes
        WHERE "typeId" IN (
            SELECT "typeId" FROM "Info"
            WHERE "infoId"=? AND "location">=?
        )
    )
    ORDER BY "id" ASC
```

Comment: You can do raw queries though in sequelize. https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/raw-queries/

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using raw queries if possible.